# How to get key values from nested JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this JSON:

```
var json = [{'range':'2012','subtotal':'116.0','total_tax':'11.6','total':'127.6'},{'range':'2013','subtotal':'936.0','total_tax':'93.6','total':'1029.6'},{'range':'2014','subtotal':'368.0','total_tax':'36.8','total':'404.8'},{'range':'2015','subtotal':'267.0','total_tax':'26.7','total':'293.7'}];
```

How can I convert this into an array of ranges like this (using Javascript or jQuery):

```
['2012', '2013', '2014', '2015']
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, that's not JSON, that's a JavaScript object literal. I'll refer to your data as `data` instead of `json`.

Second, let's use two reusable functions to express our intent more clearly

```
let map = f => x => x.map(f);
let prop = y => x => x[y];
```

Now, we simply map over your data and extract the property we want

```
map(prop('range'))(data);
// => ["2012","2013","2014","2015"]
```

**Or** we can define a reusable helper

```
let getRange = map(prop('range'));

getRange(data);
// => ["2012","2013","2014","2015"]
```

---

Here's the **ES5** equivalent

```
var map = function map(f) {
  return function (x) {
    return x.map(f);
  };
};

var prop = function prop(y) {
  return function (x) {
    return x[y];
  };
};

var getRange = map(prop('range'));

getRange(data);
// => ["2012","2013","2014","2015"]
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll mark this answer as the correct one, even though all solutions worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

You could simply use `.map`:

```
json.map(function(i) {
    return i.range;
});
//["2012", "2013", "2014", "2015"]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var mapped = json.map(function(obj) {
  return obj.range;
});
```

Also, minor point; what you have is an array. *JSON* is when an array/object is represented as a string (which happens to match the JavaScript literal notation of it)

Answer (score 1):

You actually have an array of nested objects. Here are some options:

The naive solution would be to iterate over this array and push to a new array the values you want:

```
function getRange(arr) {
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    result.push(arr[i].range)
  };
  return result;
}
```

You can also use the native Array.map method to do this easier:

```
  function getRange(arr) {
    return arr.map(function(elem) {
      return i.range;
    })
  }
```